Automorphic forms on $\mathrm{GL}_{2}$, $\mathrm{SL}_{2}$, and $\mathrm{Mp}_{2}$ — classical counterparts
I asked exact same question on MSE but haven't got answer yet, so asking here, too. I may erase the original one once I got an answer here.
--
I'm confusing about automorphic representations of $\mathrm{GL}_{2}$, $\mathrm{SL}_{2}$, and $\mathrm{Mp}_{2}$ (double cover of $\mathrm{Sp}_{2} = \mathrm{SL}_{2}$). Here's a list of my current understandings:

Classical modular forms / Maass wave forms defined on complex upper half planes can be lifted as a ($O(2)$-invariant) function on $\mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{R})$, and then adelized as a function on $\mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{A})$, which generates a space of automorphic representations. This is a pretty standard procedure, and this note explains the details.

As far as I know, automorphic representations of $\mathrm{SL}_{2}$ is not fully understood as $\mathrm{GL}_{2}$ case, and highly related to the theory of endoscopy by Labesse-Langlands. Especially, I failed to find what are the classical counterparts of automorphic representations of $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{A})$. Ramakrishnan's result on multiplicity one says that, multiplicity one implies the following: if Fourier coefficients of two eigenforms $f, g$ satisfy $a_p(f)^2 = a_p(g)^2$ for almost all $p$, then there exists a quadratic character $\chi$ such that $a_p(f) = \chi(p) a_p(g)$ for almost all $p$. Hence, it "seems" that modular forms "up to ambiguity of quadratic twist" might be a way to understand $\mathrm{SL}_{2}$ (maybe they are in the same L-packet..?). To be honest, I think I still don't fully understood why modular forms / Maass wave forms have to be understood as automorphic representations of $\mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{A})$ rather $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{A})$, although the actual construction (e.g. Booher's note above) tell us why. Note that I'm aware of the existence of this question.

Half integral weight modular forms (e.g. theta series) satisfy some complicated transformation laws and they can be viewed (adelized) as automorphic representations of $\mathrm{Mp}_{2}$, the double cover of $\mathrm{Sp}_{2} = \mathrm{SL}_{2}$. For example, the classical Shimura correspondence can be understood as a theta correspondence $\mathrm{SO}(2, 1) \times \mathrm{Mp}_{2} \subset \mathrm{Mp}_{6}$ with $\mathrm{SO}(2, 1) \simeq \mathrm{PGL}_{2}$.


Now, the third point is the origin of my confusion. Based on the holomorphic modular form / Maass wave form case, it seems more natural to associate (genuine) automorphic representation of a double cover $\widetilde{\mathrm{GL}}_{2}$ of $\mathrm{GL}_{2}$ (which can be defined in many ways, e.g. explicitly as Stienberg and Matsumoto) to half-integral weight modular forms / Maass wave forms, not $\mathrm{Mp}_{2} = \widetilde{\mathrm{SL}}_{2}$. In fact, the paper "Distinguished Representations and Modular Forms of Half-integral Weight" by Gelbart and Piatetski-Shapiro uses $\widetilde{\mathrm{GL}}_{2}$ rather than $\mathrm{Mp}_{2}$. How should I understand difference between automorphic representations of $\mathrm{Mp}_{2}$ vs $\widetilde{\mathrm{GL}}_{2}$, and what is "the" group correspond to half-integral weight forms?
